# Read XML-file from URL and save data in a DB in web - how to automate the process?

Tags: javascript, xml, database, automation, save

I have to read a XML-file from a URL; then using JS I get the information that I need from the nodes. Since only I can access the URL every x minutes (and not every user of my App) I have to save that information in a database, perhaps in my own website. Later my users will access my site for getting access to the information.

How can I automate the whole process? At least 2 times per hour a function, program or class should be triggered for:

1. getting the XML-file
2. extracting the necessary data per JS
3. saving temporarily the data in an array or text file (necessary step??)
4. saving it into a DB

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery, you can get the data from the URL using the .get() method and then parse the xml using .parseXML method.

Check out these two links for examples:

.get() Method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

.parseXML() Method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Hi,
thanks but I know how to read an XML file using .get(); perhaps I did not mention it in my first posting. The problem is the automation of the whole process.